# PHP String modification Issue

Tags: php

I am having one weird problem.I am getting time of the day like 800 , 1200 ...

i want output String like 8:00,12:00..
I know alternatives but can anyone suggests me shortest way to complete it ..?plz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*One* way to do it:

```
echo preg_replace('^(\d{1,2})(\d{2})$', '$1:$2', $time);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
echo substr($time, 0, 3 === strlen($time) ? 1 : 2) . ':' . substr($time, -2);
```

Or you can normalize the length

```
$time = str_pad($time, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);

echo substr($time, 0, 2) . ':' . substr($time, 2, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

if your source is string like "800" or "1200" then solution by deceze will do :

```
preg_replace('^(\d{1,2})(\d{2})$', '$1:$2', $time);
```

but if it's matter of date formatting then this is the right way to do it

```
date("H:i");
```